# TypeError: The view function for 'video_feed' did not return a valid response

Tags: python, flask, video-streaming

1. If it is okay to drag the img_frame used in the imported falldown_streamer and use the frame, how should I declare it
2. The view function for 'video_feed' did not return a valid response. Function returned no or terminated without a return statement. I don't know how to fix this.The view function for 'request.args.get.get_feed' did not return a valid response. Function returned no or terminated without a return statement. I get this error but I don't know how to correct it. The request.args.get part seems to be an error, but I don't know what to do

````
from picamera import PiCamera
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response ,request
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
import telepot
import time
bot = telepot.Bot('5917717036:AAFzBGj1pJr_BovFT29HGnYfSKhcJKJlkoY')
from falldown_streamer import PiVideoStream
streamer = PiVideoStream()
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
app = Flask(__name__)


def gen_frames(self):
    with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:  
        self.camera = PiCamera()
    
        self.camera.resolution = (480,320)
        self.camera.framerate = 32
        self.rawCapture = PiRGBArray(self.camera, size=(480,320))
        self.stream = self.camera.capture_continuous(self.rawCapture,
                                                     format="bgr",use_video_port=True) 
        
        time.sleep(0.1)
        # Recolor image to RGB
        image = cv2.cvtColor( img_frame , cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False
      
        # Make detection
        results = pose.process(image)
    
        # Recolor back to BGR
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        
        # Extract landmarks
        try:
            landmarks = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            
            HIP = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].y]
            NOSE = [landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].x,landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE. value].y]
            
            angle = calculate_angle(NOSE, HIP)
            
            cv2.putText(image, str(angle),
                            tuple(np.multiply(NOSE, [640, 480]).astype(int)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA
                              )
            print(landmarks)
            
            if angle < 45 :
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id = '' , text = "Fall down")
            elif angle >= 45 :
                pass
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2), 
                                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2) 
                                 )   
        except:
            pass
        

def calculate_angle(a,b):
    a=np.array(a)
    b=np.array(b)
    
    radians = np.arctan2(abs(a[1]-b[1]), abs(a[0]-b[0]))
    angle = radians*180.0/np.pi
    
    return angle

                
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index4#2.html')           

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    src = request.args.get( 'src', default = 0, type = int )
    try :
        return Response(gen_frames(src), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    except Exception as e : 
        print('[wandlab] ', 'stream error : ',str(e))


def gen_frames(self, src):
    try :     
        streamer.start(self, src )
        while True :
            frame = streamer.bytescode()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
                    
    except GeneratorExit :
        #print( '[wandlab]', 'disconnected stream' )
        streamer.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
   app.run(host="172.20.10.4", port = "9090")```
````